# how to prevent to steal my video using amazon cloudfront

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

i have created distribution id.It has following property

```
Array (
    [id] => E3VYXDXV1O9WXQ
    [status] => Deployed
    [time] => 1365430752
    [domain] => d1fhielx2etku.cloudfront.net
    [enabled] => 1
    [origin] => avijit_bucket.s3.amazonaws.com
    [originAccessIdentity] => 
    [defaultRootObject] => 
    [cnames] => Array
        (
            [mycustomvideo1.com] => mycustomvideo1.com
        )

    [trustedSigners] => Array
        (
        )

    [comment] => New distribution created )
```

What will be next step.How do i access video